# List API view returns list of empty objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use generics.ListApiView to get a list of objects, here is my serializer

```
class SitesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sites
        fields = '__all__'
```

Model

```
# domain name without www
class Sites(models.Model):
    SiteName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    DomainName = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    Currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    CurrencySymbol = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    SiteGroup = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SHOPZY_SITE_CHOICES,
                                 default=AMAZON)
```

and this is my view class

```
class SitesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Sites.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SitesSerializer
```

But instead of getting the list of site objects, i am getting a list filled with empty objects,
the output produced by the above code is

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

Whats wrong with this code? why rest framework cant show the fields of the sites object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem lies on your **`SitesSerializer`** class.
You should've use [**`serializers.ModelSerializer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) instead of `serializers.Serializer`

```
class SitesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sites
        fields = '__all__'
```